# Implementing a 2d array for an object

Tags: c++

Creating a crossword puzzle generator. The grid size is chosen by input and the grid will be generated. I'd like the grid to be an object with rows and columns but also a 2d array which will allow me to divide the grid into smaller sections for randomising between blank and numbered squares. I am not sure where to implement it.
It has to be a 2d array as I will do dividing and inverting the layout.

Here is my Grid class with some methods. (And the [rest](https://glot.io/snippets/fborl3osa3))

```
class Grid 
{
    int rows; //x
    int columns; //y
    Square field;

public:
    void SetXY(int x, int y)
    {
        rows = x;
        columns = y;
        return;
    }
public:
    void DisplaySize()
    {
        cout << "Rows = ", rows, "Columns = ", columns;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to implement a 2D array is to use a `std::array<std::array<>>` or `std::vector<std::vector<>>` - depending on whether it needs to be a static or dynamically sized array.

But, you can also just use a one dimensional `std::array` or `std::vector` and then just get the second dimension by indexing like `row*size_of_row+column`.

Comment: What is the best way of implementing the 2d array of sizes from my Grid object (rows and columns)? I tried doing this but the values must be constant.